# Best way to populate the population in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We plan to use many journeys using Journey Builder and will be using Salesforce Contact record as contact/audience source.

As you know we need to have contacts added to Contacts(Audience Builder/population) in Marketing Cloud for journeys to work.

What is best way to add data extension to population.

1. Should we create an import activity based on salesforce report of all the contacts then schedule it for new contacts and create population based this data extension?
2. Or should we base our import activity on contact object and then create population using the data extension?
3. Is there any other way to achieve the same?

Kind Regards

Comment: I believe when you wrote "MC" in ques. title it meant Marketing Cloud.

Answer (score 2):

You should use data stream and import contact object then the system will create automatically a synchronized data extension. You should create a query in order to copy the DE data into a standard DE. After that you will be able to link this DE as population into contact builder. 
This way will give you the certainty that your population is always updated.

Comment: Yes this feature is definitely the way to go. It was named Data Stream during the beta, but is now referred to as Synchronized Data Sources https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/data_sources/